# Dynamic Filter for sql query for select products

Tags: mysql

it seems my question is weird but when i explain i think you can help me to solve it.
i have these tables in database and some dummy data:
product table:

```
 --------------------------------------------
| product_id | title      | manufacturer_id |
|    1       | iphone X   | Apple           |
|    2       | galaxy s10 | Samsung         |
|    3       | galaxy A   | Samsung         |
--------------------------------------------
```

filter_group table:

```
---------------------------------
| filter_group_id | title         |
|    1            | Ram           |
|    2            | Cpu           |
|    3            | cellphone sime|
---------------------------------
```

filter_item table:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|  filter_id  |  filter_group_id |   title    |
|      1      |        1         |     2GB    |
|      2      |        1         |     4GB    |
|      3      |        1         |     8GB    |
|      4      |        1         |     1GB    |
|      5      |        2         |     Corei7 |
|      6      |        2         |     Corei5 |
|      7      |        3         |     1-cell |
|      8      |        3         |     2-cell |
-----------------------------------------------
```

product_filter table:

```
---------------------------
| product_id  | filter_id |
|    1        |     2     |
|    1        |     8     |
|    2        |     2     |
|    2        |     8     |
|    2        |     6     |
|    3        |     2     |
---------------------------
```

so now i want to create a advanced search form that filter products by filters.
i will show all filter group and filter to choose with user and i want filter products with filter_data that is post to server
how should write SQL query for this example
please note that all filter_group and filter are dynamic and can add or remove

for example if user choose these Filters [4GB, 2-cell] : i want to show product 1 and 2 and not 3
how can i write this query

i want filter data with filter_group (1,3) and filter data with filter(2)
its MySQL Database